# HTML5/CSS3 classless framework

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know of a simple HTML5/CSS3 framework which applies a minimum of formatting with no need for custom class names? Ideally it would take only properly laid-out HTML5, and would position elements with a minimum of flexibility, using common rules for, say sidebar widths and the like.

With HTML5 there much less need for custom class names, with elements like `header`, `nav` or `aside`, but I haven't yet seen a framwork taking full advantage of that. Any ideas?

**Clarification:** I've been through all the usual suspects (Bootstrap, HTML% Boilerplate, Shim and the like), and none of them scratches my itch. And that itch is a simple combo of plain HTML5 structure which assumes nothing about the design but defines everything semantically, with a simple CSS3 stylesheet which defines the actual layout. I can envision it using several stylesheets, with a base one defining the layout of elements and separate one(s) for actual design. It would be used as a simple starting point for various projects, which could be later customized individually.

Apparently, I might need to go the way proposed by Wesley and write one myself...

Comment: Do you want CSS framework without classes?

Comment: Personally I use twitter bootstrap, it's very well designed in my opinion, and pretty flexible http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: I imagine it's possible with child and sibling selectors, but it's a house of cards as soon as you need to change your HTML.

Comment: What you describe sounds closer to a CSS preprocessor. Try SASS.

Comment: I've collected all the classless CSS stylesheets I was able to find [here](https://github.com/waldyrious/downstyler/issues/29#issuecomment-387060711), and will eventually add the list to the project's README. Any additions are most welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is not a CSS framework, but just a simple custom stylesheet.

Not to discourage your effort in looking for something that already exists, but you're better off writing it yourself. Perhaps start off with one of the many existing `reset.css`. Default styles without the ability to hook in (or out) via class names are not very flexible.

You really shouldn't avoid classes, you should take advantage of them. No framework is going to know where and how your HTML elements are nested or what they're supposed to look like based on tag name alone, that's one reason why we usually use classes.

If you pay close attention to the semantics of the new HTML5 elements, you'll see that `header` doesn't always mean "the top of your page with your logo", `footer` is not just an element for the bottom of your whole page, and `aside` doesn't always equate to "sidebar".

Comment: You are correct, "stylesheet" is more accurate term than "framework".

Answer (score 4):

I found a very similar need and ended up making my own project: https://github.com/oxalorg/sakura

You just need to drop in `sakura.css` and you're good to go, no changes required to HTML.

Here's a **demo**: https://oxal.org/projects/sakura/demo/

Answer (score 3):

You can start off your HTML5 application with the HTML5 Boilerplate.

Dan Wahlin posted a good blog post on getting it set up:

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2011/06/05/getting-started-using-html5-boilerplate.aspx

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/herrshuster/style.css

This is my current project. It's not quite ready for deployment yet, but it's exactly what you're looking for. I'd love any suggestions you have or if you'd like to talk about it.
[This is a test page where you can see the semantic layout](http://herrshuster.github.io/style.css/)

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a great project, I'll look into it some more!

Answer (score 2):

There's a good list of classless and classlight CSS themes over at https://github.com/dbohdan/classless-css, complete with screenshots! Also, you can preview several different themes using the dropdown on https://dohliam.github.io/dropin-minimal-css/, nice to see what each of them look like.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with it myself, but you may find [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) helpful. It uses a grid system that allows you to easily position elements on the page. This may be particularly useful for creating areas for sidebars and other common features on pages.

However, it is somewhat opposite of what you're suggesting as it uses classes quite heavily. From what I've seen though, the classes are treated in a very structured manner so may be close to what you're looking for.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. It is extremely class heavy, but it does offer great UI components.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested in this topic, I recommend reading the [articles by Heydon Pickering](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/author/heydon-pickering/), who built [his blog](http://www.heydonworks.com/) theme without using any classes.

---

I also recommend checking out [my project](https://github.com/fiatjaf/unitemplate) that aims to create a [fundamental classless HTML template](https://github.com/fiatjaf/unitemplate/blob/gh-pages/unitemplate.html) for blogs and blog-like websites (every website with a title and an author, with pages, posts and sections) and add pure CSS themes on top of it. The template makes heavy usage of HTML5 sectioning, headers and footers and smallish assumptions of in which section you should put each website content. The [themes](https://github.com/fiatjaf/unitemplate/tree/gh-pages/themes) are ports of other framework-specific themes on the internet.

There's a [playground](http://fiatjaf.alhur.es/unitemplate/playground) where you can test the themes on various HTML pages based on the fundamental template (just write the theme name on the box, or paste a CSS url). There's also a [bad old article](http://fiatjaf.alhur.es/programming/reusable-pure-css-themes/) I wrote while trying to think about the subject.

Answer (score 1):

[Pico CSS](https://picocss.com/) has a [classless version](https://picocss.com/docs/classless.html) which does **exactly** what you've specified.